# jailbreak detection exit App after 5 seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, detection

i want use this Code in my App:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];

 // Jailbreak Detection

 NSString *cydiaFilePath = @"/Applications/Cydia.app";

 if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:cydiaFilePath])
 {
     // insert jailbreak code here...

     UIAlertView *jailbreakDetection = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                        initWithTitle:@"Jailbreak Detected"
                                        message:@"This application will not run while a jailbreak is installed."
                                        delegate:nil
                                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];

     [jailbreakDetection show];
 } }
```

And this Code still works. But i don't get an Button to Close the message and i want finish the App after close this Message.

Please can anyone help me to fix this? I don't understand it, i dont know what i do wrong.

Comment: `cancelButtonTitle:nil` and `otherButtonTitles:nil`... so what button do you exactly expect from a `nil` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the cancel button and other button's titles to nil. You should set some title for the cancel button:

```
UIAlertView *jailbreakDetection = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                        initWithTitle:@"Jailbreak Detected"
                                              message:@"This application will not run while a jailbreak is installed."
                                             delegate:nil
                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Okay this i understand, i need to use the Button.

Comment: how i can integrate the app stop runing after push the Button?

Comment: @tim I don't think that you can make your app "stop running" other than by throwing an uncaught exception or something similar. Even if there was a simple way to close your app, I doubt that apple would approve it for the app store.

Comment: but i need a way to stop it. my Idea was to use a timer of 5 seconds and then finish the App by exit(0); but all my try don't works.

Comment: As per apple's guidelines programmatically one should not close the application. An app should quit only when the user clicks the home button. 

okay then i can't use `exit(0);` by the Guidelines of Apple. So then i need to think new. Can i make the UIAlertView bigger on the screen? An my second question is, i want check more path then only this one:   

    `NSString *cydiaFilePath = @"/Applications/Cydia.app";`

for me normaly think like this:

    `NSString *cydiaFilePath = @"/Applications/Cydia.app", @"/Applications/oXn.app";`

But this not works. whats wrong about my Way?